# Клонирование элемента и изменение свойства

Tags: jquery, javascript

Допустим, клонирование элемента происходит таким образом:

```
$(th).closest(this.parent).find(this.title).clone();
```

Этот элемент - есть **ссылка**.
Далее для клонированного элемента хочу сменить текст:

```
$(this.title_save_element).text(newTitle);
```

Что не сработало.

> Элемент: <div class="namePost"><a
> href="/4">text</a></div>

Клонирование элемента **.namePost a**

Comment: Что за элемент? div или input, или что-то другое? И покажите полностью код, не совсем понятно.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: $(th).closest(this.parent).find(this.title).clone();

Тут вы скопировали элемент (Скопировали ли? Корректно ли отработали селекторы `$(th).closest(this.parent).find(this.title)`? ), и, я так понимаю, сохранили ссылку в `this.title_save_element`.

Чему равно `this.title_save_element`? Посмотрите в дебаггере.

Когда вы клонировали элемент, вы его в DOM вставили?

 - Если вам просто нужна ссылка на элемент, то клонировать его не нужно.
 - Если же вы клонируете элемент, то он болтается у вас в памяти, и его нужно вставить в DOM.

Comment: В одном методе делаю так: `$(this.title_save_element).text('test')` - это работает. Но если в другом методе сделать `html(this.title_save_element);` то в this.title_save_element нет ранее вставленного текста.